# After training how can I see how much compute resource was used for a given model?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I have a model that I trained using google cloud AutoML vision. I wish to know how much compute time it took to do the training and how much that model cost to train.

I asked google help the same question and got the response below. Ironically it seems as if they are just forwarding help requests to a chat bot!

> Hello Felix,
>
> Thank you for contacting Google Cloud Platform Billing Support.
>
> I do understand you need assistance about AutoML usage and pricing,
>   let me assist.
>
> I have taken the initiative to review the Billing Account ID
>   [xxxxx] and found that there is AutoML Image Object
>   Detection On-Device Model Training credit for $ 435.54 NZD. I took
>   time to compute the resources of Cloud Vision API AutoML Object
>   Detection On-Device Model Training Node and it is valid because of the
>   pricing of this resources. You may check the SKU page [1] for details.
>   On top of AutoML Image Object Detection On-Device Model Training
>   credit, there is the free trial credit of $ 480.03 NZD that also
>   covers the usages. Please note that free trial automatically ends once
>   the credit is consumed or the 12-month period is over, whichever comes
>   first [2].
>
> For now, AutoML Image Object Detection On-Device Model Training credit
>   for $ 435.54 NZD is the only model being consumed. AutoML Image Object
>   Detection Online Prediction and AutoML Video Object Tracking Model
>   Training still have remaining credit.
>
> I hope this information points you in the right direction. Please
>   don't hesitate to reply to this email should you have any
>   Cloud-related billing questions as I will be sure to keep this case
>   open.
>
> Regards,
>
> Livy Google Cloud Platform Billing Support
>
> [1] - https://cloud.google.com/skus/?currency=NZD&filter=E5DF-9EA2-4596 
>   [2] - https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#end

Comment: I'd also like to know the billing cost to train a model. The billing system only seems to show a monthly summary.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
If you remember the time when you started training your model(**start time**), you'll get a mail after your training got finished(**end time**). Calculate the difference between these two times to know how much time it took to complete the training.

**Solution 2:**

Go to **Activity**(tab next to **Dashboard**) in your Google Cloud Platform
https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity

In this Activity tab you can see all your activity details.

Look for Create model.(You can find the training start time of your model here)

Check for training finished mail(This is the end time)
Calculate difference between these two times.

Comment: I want to know the compute time. In other words how much compute resource was used. The clock time is next to useless to compare with other training systems.